AWS how connect two VPC in same account but overlapping CIDR
Right now have a VPC where is my RDS in a private subnet, also I have a ECS in the same VPC and both have communication, now the problem is that I have a new ECS but in another VPC, first I tried  to do a VPC peering, but bot VPC have the CIDR overlapping. What can I do?
I expect to have a solution for my problem

I think AWS PrivateLink or a self build NAT-ing solution are possibilities. See https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/connecting-networks-with-overlapping-ip-ranges/
Dependent on what kind of services you want to connect you might also have a look at Amazon VPC Lattice https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/lattice/

You can't peer overlapping VPCs. You can create attachments to a Transit Gateway for overlapping VPCs, BUT it will not let you propagate two identical CIDRs, and only the first route is propagated so it's not routable.
The easiest way around this (without faffing with S2S VPNS + NATs or AWS Private NAT GW + TGW) is using AWS Private Link. It is useful for Producer/Consumer architectures and is compatible with over-lapping CIDRs as it uses VPC Endpoints.
Here is more info: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/create-endpoint-service.html
